# Coordinates of click

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to use [HERE js sdk](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/overview.html).

I'm add a `tap`-event listener to map. How to get the actual coord of a tap.

I finished with code bellow:

```
let tapHandler = (evt) => {
  console.log(evt.currentTarget.getCenter())
}
```

but it actually returns an initial center of the Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get coordinates from the map with:

```
clickCoords = map.screenToGeo(e.viewportX, e.viewportY);
```

Comment: thanks! Actually I figured it out yesterday but I spent a lot of time with debugger. Did I miss something or documentation says nothing about this thing?

Comment: Page 88 in Developer Guide for HERE JS API version 3 it has a nice example for that. One page 105 it has the reference guide mentioning all methods on Map object. Please notice that it sometimes scrolls you to developer guide v2.5.x when you are on developer.here.com and click on JS API guide V3, there you obviously don't find anything about that. :)

Comment: Where can somebody get a Developer Guide?)